# How to Implement Search Functionality in Wso2

Tags: wso2-esb

I need to Implement a Search Functionality (It needs to retrieve a data in Database) ex: abc. Rest API need to search the string in database and if record matches found will send all the records relevant to abc. Could anyone please help me

Comment: What part do you need help with. Have you tried implementing any of the things that you listed in the question (Creating the API, searching the Database)?

Comment: The help I need is how to handle the Search Functionality ? Yes, I tried Only Creating an API but I have not tried searching in Database. That is the reason I posted

Answer (score 0):

You can use WSO2 EI.

Follow the steps in [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Sending+a+Simple+Message+to+a+Datasource) to create a data service. Then you can test that service through CURL or postman.

Then create an API, which will call the data service and respond the message received by the data service. If you want to manipulate the message received by data service, use payload factory or XSLT transformation.